# Display XY data loading in wrong place

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, coordinates

I have a tabular data set that contains eastings and northings and LAT and LONG  data. I check some points manually with the ArcGIS "go to xy" point tool and they al appear to be in the correct place on a base map. However, after numerous attempts at bringing the data into arc and using "display xy data" to place them on the map I still end up with the data being projected in the wrong place and to the wrong scale.
What could be causing this, and how do I fix it?

I am operating with ArcGIS, Displaying in Decimal Degrees, WGS 1984 WM (Data frame coord system)

Projected Coordinate System: 
  Name: WGS_1984_World_Mercator

Geographic Coordinate System: 
  Name: GCS_WGS_1984

Comment: Hard to know without more info.  Please [edit] to include a sample of your coordinates and some detail as to how they're in the wrong place/wrong scale when you enter them (a screenshot or two may be useful).  Outline your "display XY data" process.

Comment: Are the checked points in the same place as their matching processed points?

Comment: if there in decimal degrees bring them in with WGS84/4326 then project the layer to your projected coordinate system

Comment: Just to verify that you are importing correctly..x,y is actually long, lat. That throws a lot of people when they are getting started with GIS & coordinate systems. If you are inverting them, you will get results that are way off. (lat = y,  long = x)

Comment: Reiterating @ziggy comment. The Add XY tool defaults the coordinate system to the data frame's. If the xy data is lat/lon, you have to change it from the default.